# Best way to write Util Class

Tags: java, memory-management, static, singleton

I'm new to Java
I want to write util classes for my own purposes such as FileUtil,DBUtil,...

But some people write all methods in util classes as static methods

```
class FileUtil{
    public static File openFile(String path){
        ...
    }
    public static File readFile(String path){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and some  write util class as singleton classes and write methods as public

```
class FileUtil{
    private FileUtil(){}
    public FileUtil getInstance(){
        ...
    }
    public File openFile(String path){
        ...
    }
    public File readFile(String path){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to know which is better way of doing it when it comes to memory allocation
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're likely to want to mock it, then an instance (of an interface...?) might end up being easier to work with. Otherwise, individual taste, I guess.

Comment: *I want to know which is better way of doing it when it comes to memory allocation* The singleton version has exactly one more instance than the non-singleton version. Clearly it uses *slightly* more memory.

Comment: @Raghav First approach with a private constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never write a singleton. If you really want static fields (don't) then write `static`. For (single implementation) utility methods there's no point in forcing an extra object on the client.

Look at the mess created by `Runtime` vs `System` despite being essentially the same thing.

Traditionally utility classes are written as classes with static methods. A private constructor that throws an exception can be added to prevent the default constructor being added, but adds extra mess to the code (though reduces documentation). Also adding an unnecessary `final` is common.

Single-element enums were popular for singletons (don't write singletons). Using the same arguments utility classes should be no-element enums, though that isn't popular for no obvious reason. Both single and no element enums add nonsense methods to the class.

If you really want concise code, use interfaces. You avoid having to write `public` every time and constants can elide the `public static`. This is apparently not very popular because it is possible for clients to ruin their own code by implementing the interface. See Swing.

Answer (score 0):

## Utilities:

Utility classes are classes that do not need any instance. They provide **methods** that help you to do things.

## Singletons:

Singletons are instances that require to have **one and only one** instance. The reason for having singletons are various, maybe you need a single coordinator that should not be interferred...

## FileUtil:

well the name points it out already, this class provides **methods** for a simplified file access...

## FileManager:

this **object** is responsible to keep track of the integrity of the file System. Noone else is allowed to create/delete files but only the FileManger, hence FileManager would be a **singleton**. (Your Questions doesn't ask for a File Manager, but to make a difference to FileUtils i think it would be helpful)

## Memory Usage / Clean Code

why this answer: you think you might optimize for memory but clean code points out that [you should not optimize](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Beware_of_Optimizations)

## Summary:

don't use a Singleton if you really don't have to do it. Use a plain utility class (it's by the way the thing you wanted to do).